# How to solve this linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've tried solving this system of equations using Gauss-Jordan( I don't know how could I solve it any other way)

\begin{array}{c}
x-y+2z-2t=-5 \\ 
2x+3y-z+t=5 \\ 
3x+y+2z-2t=-3 \\
4x-y+5z-5t=-11
\end{array}

And using Gauss-Jordan, I've arrived to this matrix:

\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
   1 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -5  \\
   2 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 5 \\
   1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
   0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -3 \\ 
   \end{array}

After this set of operations R3+R4, R3:7, R4-2R2, R4:7.

Comment: In the last equation, should it be $ 4x - y ... $?

Comment: @hjpotter92 my bad. I edited it.

Comment: You're supposed to arrive first at an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Hint: Find the row reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix.

Comment: @Tomath is it possible for the system to not be solvable?

Comment: Yes. It can happen. In that case,  you'd get a row 
in the row reduced echelon matrix, consisting of 0, except for the entry corresponding to the column for constant terms.

Comment: `And using Gauss-Jordan, I've arrived to this matrix:` -- I wouldn't say that you have arrived anywhere yet. You've performed a few steps, but why stop now? In applying the Gauss-Jordan method, your goal is at least to achieve a row echelon form, or better yet the reduced row echelon form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve it in $5$ steps. I leave it to you to find the row operations that were performed:

\begin{align}&\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1&-1&2&-2&-5 \\ 2&3&-1&1&5 \\3&1&2&-2&-3\\4&-1&5&-5&-11\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1&-1&2&-2&-5 \\ 0&5&-5&5&15 \\0 & 4 & -4 & 4 & 12\\ 0&3&-3&3&9
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} \\
\rightsquigarrow 
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1&-1&2&-2&-5 \\ 0&1&-1&1&3 \\0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 3\\ 0&1&-1&1&3
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} \rightsquigarrow  
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1&-1&2&-2&-5\\ 0&1&-1&1&3 \\0 & 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
\rightsquigarrow
&  
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1&0&1&-1&-2\\ 0&1&-1&1&3 \\0 & 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} \
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-The given equations are not  independent. You proved it if you look carefully to get what equation is a linear combination of the other ones. Or if you want, calculating the determinant of the matrix to get that
$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 
      1 & -1 & 2&-2 \\ 
      2 & 3 & -1&1 \\ 
      3 & 1 & 2&-2\\4&-1&5&-5       
   \end{pmatrix}=0$$
You have then an infinity of solutions(or maybe none).

You can get $x+y=1$, in particular.